# How to count even numbers in a user input list

Tags: python, arrays, list, count

I'm fairly new to python and just coding all together and I'm totally stumped. I can't seem to find a more noobish simple explanation to how to get the count of the number of even numbers entered by a user into a list. Any advice or ideas are welcomed thank you very much.

Comment: Please keep the code you had tried. It'll help people to answer in a better way !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An even number is always divisible by 2, so you can use the `modulus` (%) operator to check if each number in the array is even. If that number is even, you can increment a counter for the number of even numbers. You do this every time you iterate through an element in the list.

```
define evenCount

go through each number in the list
    if the number is even (divisible by 2)
        increment evenCount
```

Here is the actual code:

```
listSize = int(input("Enter the list size: "))
numbers = []
evenCount = 0

for i in range(listSize):
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    numbers.append(number)

for number in numbers:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        evenCount = evenCount + 1

print(evenCount)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
def GetEvenCount(inputList):
    return sum(1-n%2 for n in inputList)
```

Comment: can you please explain ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
>>> l=list(map(int, input('enter space separated list elements: ').split()))
enter space separated list elements: 1 2 3 4 5 6
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> print('Number of even elements: '+str(len(list(filter(lambda x:x%2==0, l)))))
Number of even elements: 3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter to count the inputs that have 0 reminder for divide by 2:

```
numbers = list()
counter = 0
while(True):
    data = input("Enter number ('E' for exit): ")
    if data == 'E':
        break
    numbers.append(data)
    if int(data)%2 ==0:
        counter +=1

print (numbers)
print (counter)
```

Works as below:

```
>>> 
==================== RESTART: C:/Windows/System32/test.py ====================
Enter number ('E' for exit): 1
Enter number ('E' for exit): 2
Enter number ('E' for exit): 3
Enter number ('E' for exit): 4
Enter number ('E' for exit): 5
Enter number ('E' for exit): 6
Enter number ('E' for exit): E
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
3
>>>
```